# Count number of unique element in a list

Tags: tcl

Say I have a list, `a b c b b d e e f …`, and I don't know how many different kind of elements are in there.

How do I count the number of each unique element and print them out?
Output would looks like:

```
a: 32
b: 12
c: 6
…
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to count them up. This isn't too hard with an array or dictionary of counters. I'll use a dictionary since then they'll be printed in order of first occurrence. (With an array, you'd get a “random” order or you'd have to sort them.)

```
set counters {}
foreach item $list {
    dict incr counters $item
}
dict for {item count} $counters {
    puts "${item}: $count"
}
```

Comment: `dict` makes this, pretty much, an 8.6 only solution. Many platforms still offer only 8.5 or even earlier -- I would've used `array` instead. For this purpose either one works well.

Comment: How to make this happen in arrary?

Comment: @Bryan: three changes: line 1 `unset counters`; line 3 `incr counters($item)`; line 5 `foreach {item count} [array get counters] {`.

Comment: (`array set counters {}` works too, and is more in line with Donal's code.)

Comment: `dict` is in 8.5, and 8.4 is unsupported. If a platform offers only 8.4 it is seriously outdated. 8.5 is just 9 years old by now. So lets just hope the 'many' is mostly legacy RHEL installations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you have 8.4 or older version of TCL,

```
set lst "a a a a b b b c c c d d a a a f f f f f s s s s"

set unique [lsort -unique $lst]    
foreach f $unique {
    set cnt 0
    foreach item $lst {
        if {$item == $f} {
            incr cnt
        }
    }
    puts "$f :: $cnt"
}
```

Gives Output Like,

```
% tclsh main.tcl
a :: 7
b :: 3                                                                                                                                                              
c :: 3
d :: 2                                                                                                                                                              
f :: 5
s :: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done using lsearch and llength.
Lets say your list is {a c a c s a a c a} then,

```
set tempList {a c a c s a a c a}  
puts "c : [llength [lsearch -all $tempList  c]]"  
puts "a : [llength [lsearch -all $tempList  a]]"  
puts "d : [llength [lsearch -all $tempList  d]]"
```

Output :
c : 3
a : 5
d : 0

Explanation : lsearch -all, will return all the index of matching element
and this list of index is returned to llength which will count length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` or `array` solution is the best one and should be preferred. Another way that works on a sorted list of tokens is to match contiguous regions of non-blank tokens.

```
% regexp -all -inline {(\S+)(?:\s+\1)*} {a a b b b c d d}
{a a} a {b b b} b c c {d d} d
```

The result is an even-sized list of alternately matched regions of tokens and the token matched in the region. This can be used to print a frequency report for the tokens in the list in `list`.

```
foreach {a b} [regexp -all -inline {(\S+)(?:\s+\1)*} [lsort $list]] {
    puts "$b: [llength $a]"
}
```

Note the limitation that the tokens cannot contain blanks. This can be overcome, but it's simpler to use the array / dict solution which only requires the tokens to be valid list elements.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm)